# OnActivityResult is not calling in TabGroupActivity

Tags: android, tabs, activitygroup

I have an tabactivity with four tabs

Home->Tab1->Activity1->Activity2[image]

In Activity2 I have a text box. When I click textbox I am showing CalenderActivity like below
 [image: activity2]

When click date it has to display the date in text box; for that I write onActivityResult in Activity3 but that is not calling. What do I have to do to display date in textbox? I am using TabGroupActivity to navigate between activities in a single tab...

Answer (score 0):

You call the child activity as

```
getParent().startActivityForResult(schedule, req_code);
```

and write the function that you want to do in onActivityresult() of tabgropActivity